# Property declaration on first vs last places on mongo query?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm making query for retrieving data on mango collection, i have making same query in two different way.

**working query:**

```
db.getCollection('routes').find({"routes.routeId": "r1qJo2zWG"}, {routes : {"$elemMatch": {"routeId": "r1qJo2zWG"}}})
```

**not working query:**

```
db.getCollection('routes').find({routes : {"$elemMatch": {"routeId": "r1qJo2zWG"}}}, {"routes.routeId": "r1qJo2zWG"})
```

query working is depends on property declaration such as "routes.routeId" in first/last position.

give idea why this will happen on mongodb query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing query and projection. Both the queries are working as expected.

[`find`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/method/db.collection.find/#definition) method takes both query and projection.

**First Example** ( Valid )

```
db.getCollection('routes').find({"routes.routeId": "r1qJo2zWG"}, {routes : {"$elemMatch": {"routeId": "r1qJo2zWG"}}})
```

Query Part

```
{"routes.routeId": "r1qJo2zWG"}
```

Projection Part

```
{routes : {"$elemMatch": {"routeId": "r1qJo2zWG"}}}
```

You are querying for all documents where routes array has a routeId with the value "r1qJo2zWG" followed by [`$elemMatch(projection)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) to limit the routes elements to output the matching route with a routeId value of "r1qJo2zWG"

**Second Example** (  Invalid )

```
db.getCollection('routes').find({routes : {"$elemMatch": {"routeId": "r1qJo2zWG"}}}, {"routes.routeId": "r1qJo2zWG"})
```

Query Part

```
{routes : {"$elemMatch": {"routeId": "r1qJo2zWG"}}}
```

Projection Part

```
{"routes.routeId": "r1qJo2zWG"}
```

You are querying for all documents using  [`$elemMatch(query)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) where routes array has a routeId with the value "r1qJo2zWG" ( which is exactly same as {"routes.routeId": "r1qJo2zWG"} and `$elemMatch` operator is not required for single criteria matches ) followed by invalid projection {"routes.routeId": "r1qJo2zWG"}.

The correct projection if used should be {"routes.routeId": 1} to display all the route id values for routes array.